# Getting Routing Error /stylesheets/application in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Searched everywhere for an answer but couldn't find it.
So I'm using Rails 7 and on my /app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss added `@import "bootstrap";`.
Everything works fine but I still get this error message:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application"):
```

Does anyone have the same issue or know if there's anything I can do to "repair" it?

Thanks on advance